# How to run a long running python script in background from Flask Rest API?

Tags: python, flask, subprocess, python-multithreading

I have a flask rest API setup correctly.
Once I hit the rest API, I want to run a python script/function and return with a runID and then user can hit another rest API with the runID to get information.

How can I return immediately and keep another python script/function running in another thread/process?

Following is my rest API

```
@app.route('/start/', methods=['POST'])
def start_run():
    run_id = "SOME RANDOM NUMBER"
    # I want to start python script here
    return run_id

@app.rout('/get_report', methods=['GET'])
def get_report():
    run_id = request.args("run_id")
    return some_method(run_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Running long-running background task is a complex process for singleton `wsgi` based project. Best approach is to use some kind of background scheduler like celery, apschedular. This answer based on celery approach.

There is good tutorial for how to run [celery background task](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/) and you can use that in your project.

Take look for below example.

```
@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b

result = add_together.delay(23, 42) # Create celery instance for this job
print(result.request.id) # Print celery task id
```

By default celery provide state and you can use that as well.

```
task = result.AsyncResult(task_id)
print(task.state)
```